# If we remove 'the' in "Gone with the Wind"

Tags: definite-article

I was talking to a native speaker some time ago, she was a young adult. And when I mentioned the movie *Gone with the Wind*, she corrected me, saying that the right title was *Gone with Wind*. But we know that it is not true.

I was pondering it and arrived at the conclusion that when you use *wind* without the definite article, it has a literal meaning—movements of bodies of air. But in the title, I think, it has a figurative meaning; maybe *the wind* is the civil war, some other circumstances, or the passage of time.

Am I right that if you remove *the* from *the wind*, it becomes difficult to attach any figurative meaning to it, and it simply becomes *wind* as a physical phenomenon?

Comment: Very interesting! It's very curious that she chose to drop the *the* and didn't change *Wind* to *Winds* or *a Wind*. -- (That doesn't mean that *wind* can only be a countable noun.)

Comment: Incidentally, _Gone with Wind_ sounds like _Wind_ is a name and someone eloped with her.

Comment: @helix: I think that would be as perverse as thinking *gone with the wind* implies someone went somewhere with all the musicians in an orchestra's wind section. Obviously there could be situations where such interpretations are perfectly correct, but they're somewhat unlikely.

Comment: It does become a physical phenomenon (note "phenomena" is plural), but it can also be figurative.  [This](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-wind) is a rather amusing example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very common to use "the" when referring to "the elements" (that is, to [weather](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/element?q=elements)).

- *Singin’ in [the](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045152/) Rain*
- *Blowin’ in [the](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowin%27_in_the_Wind) Wind*
- *A Walk in [the](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038235/) Sun*
- *Cipher in [the](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368645/) Snow*
- *Under [the](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2373396/) Clouds of Love*

I'm guessing that your friend caught hold of this silly notion that we use *a* to refer to a generic instance, and *the* when referring to a particular instance already named or known – as if those are the only times we use those articles. Not so! (In fact, that's one of the most common erroneous perceptions I've encountered on ELL.)

Truth is, that *generic-vs.-particular* instance is just [one of many](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the_1) ways these articles are used; most dictionaries will list about a dozen more. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the), for example, says the following about *the*:

> - used preceding certain nouns associated with one's culture, society, or community
>     ⇒ *go to the doctor, listen to the news*
> - used preceding present participles and adjectives when they function as nouns
>     ⇒ *the singing is awful, the dead salute you*
> - used preceding a noun to make it refer to its class generically
>     ⇒ *the white seal is hunted for its fur, this is good for the throat, play the piano*
> - used instead of my, your, her, etc, with parts of the body
>     ⇒ *take me by the hand*

If I say,

> *I'll be back in a little while; I'm going to go listen to the radio*.

nobody asks me, "Which radio?", and nobody corrects me, saying that I should have said, "I'm going to go listen to radio," because *"listen to* **the** *radio"* is idiomatic.

Had Mitchell entitled her book *Gone with Wind*, it would have sounded awkward. She got it right.

---

You mention the figurative use of *the wind* to mean *troubling events, Civil War, or the passage of time*. Indeed, that's what the title refers to – irrespective of the presence of the article. In fact, Mitchell wasn't the first (or last) to use *the wind* figuratively or metaphorically. King Solomon analogized with [*chasing the wind*](http://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/2-11.htm). And when Kansas sings *Dust in the Wind*, you didn't think they were talking about a dust storm, did you?

> *I close my eyes only for a moment, and the moment's gone
>
>   All my dreams pass before my eyes, a curiosity*
>
> *Dust in the wind, all they are is dust in the wind*
>
> *Same old song, just a drop of water in an endless sea
>
>   All we do crumbles to the ground, though we refuse to see*
>
> *Dust in the wind, all we are is dust in the wind*

Incidentally, *crumbles to **the** ground* is the correct way to express it – not "crumbles to ground."

Comment: Incidentally, “gone with the wind” comes from a poem by Oscar Wilde's friend Ernest Dowson. Margaret Mitchell said it had “the far away, faintly sad sound I wanted.”

Answer (score 14):

The idea that including the article or not has any bearing on whether the intended sense is figurative or not is completely misplaced. The idiomatic ***passed by, disappeared*** usage has been around [since at least 1832](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0k8hAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA192&dq=%22have%20gone%20with%20the%20wind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X4w9U7jKGMmH0AWCx4CgBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22have%20gone%20with%20the%20wind%22&f=false), and the literal sense (***drift*** or ***[intentionally] travel in the same direction as the wind***) has been around much longer. But the article is always present in both usages.

In fact, we normally include the definite article in such references to natural phenomena...

> *He [ran like **the** wind](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22ran%20like%20the%20wind%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *Her mood can [change like **the** weather](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22change%20like%20the%20weather%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *Early risers [get up with **the** sun](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22get%20up%20with%20the%20sun%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *Economic cycles are as [regular as **the** seasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22regular%20as%20the%20seasons%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *The course of my life is [written in **the** stars](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22is%20written%20in%20the%20stars%22&start=20&tbm=bks)*
>    *Prostitutes are still sometimes called [ladies of **the** night](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22ladies%20of%20the%20night%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *I still need you at the [dimming of **the** day](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22dimming%20of%20the%20day%22&start=10&tbm=bks)*
>    etc., etc.

---

Various idiomatic usages where we *don't* include the article are the exception rather than the rule...

> *Obviously he loves you! It's [as plain as day](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22plain%20as%20day%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *We [travelled by sea](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22travelled%20by%20sea%22&tbm=bks)*
>    *We work hard all day, so [come evening,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20with%20the%20wind%22&biw=1196&bih=873&sa=X&ei=Ko89U8-3B8yThgeXz4GQCQ&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1630,cd_max:12/31/1760&tbm=bks#q=%22come%20evening%20we%22&tbm=bks) we're exhausted*

Answer (score 1):

"To have wind" is to be flatulent so I'm afraid I parse "Gone with wind" as "Went while farting".

Answer (score 0):

Without "the"  it sounds unusual and curious. I would not try to read things into the title ( with or without article). 
" the wind"  is  the normal
meteorological phenomenon that can carry away things when it is strong 
just as the water of a river can carry away things.
I can think of no logical reason why here the article is used, maybe just for rhythmic reasons, and I don't know whether
in all such expressions "the" is used, but I think it is "It happened/was due to the  rain/ the snow/the cold/the heat/
the drought.